# Proof without words: $1+8\times\text{triangular number}$ is an odd perfect square

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof, proof-without-words

A recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281906/137524) asked how to show that $8T_n+1$ is a perfect square if $T_n$ is a triangular number. This follows immediately from $T_n=\frac12 n(n+1)\implies 8T_n+1=4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2$.

Can this be proven without words?

Comment: If this seems like a silly question...well, probably it is. But I'm fond of such visual proofs, so this is what sprang to mind when I saw the other question.

Comment: I'm not very adept at art, so I'll just describe with words: have eight copies of right-triangular arrays of dots of height and length $n$.  Rotate and fit the triangles together along the hypotenuses to have now four $n\times (n+1)$ rectangular arrays.  Fit these together to form a square missing the center hole of side-length $2n+1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I was just realizing that. Silly of me not to have spotted it sooner! In fact, that very image shows up on Mathworld's page for the triangular numbers: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularNumber.html.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer turns out to be quite simple, as @JMoravitz notes in his comment. In fact, Mathworld's page on triangular numbers includes precisely the right image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} \\
\color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} \\
\color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} \\
\color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} & \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} & \color{green}{\bullet} \\
\color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{orange}{\bullet} & \color{black}{\circ} & \color{purple}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} \\
\color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} \\
\color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} \\
\color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{purple}{\bullet} \\
\color{cyan}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{magenta}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet} & \color{yellow}{\bullet}
\end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

And you can convert
the proof without words
back into algebra
(which has the advantage of
showing that 
it is true
for any $n$):

$\begin{array}\\
8T_n
&=4(2T_n)\\
&=4(2(\frac{n(n+1}{2}))\\
&=4(n(n+1))\\
&=4n^2+4n\\
&=4n^2+4n+1-1\\
&=(2n+1)^2-1\\
\end{array}
$