# Triangular Numbers and Perfect Squares

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

> Prove that $n$ is a triangular number if and only if $8n+1$ is a perfect square.

I proved the easier part first (I think), that is, if $n$ is a triangular number then $8n+1$ is a perfect square.

I don't know where to start from for the other part, please help.

*By the way, this was taken from David Burton's book, Elementary Number Theory and sadly it doesn't have all the  solutions...*

Comment: Almost trivial: $$ N=\frac{M(M+1)}{2}\Longleftrightarrow 8N+1 = (2M+1)^2$$

Comment: Oh, forgot that $n$ couldn't be even..., Thanks a lot!

Comment: Start and the beginning.  Go on to the middle.  And when you get to the end-- stop.  If $8n + 1 = m^2$ then $8n = m^2 - 1 = (m-1)(m+1)$ so $n= \frac {(m-1)(m+1)}8$ is an integer.  So $2$ either divides $m-1$ or $m+1$ but as $m-1, m+1$ are either both even or both odd so they are both even.  Let $m-1 = 2k$ then $m+1 = (m-1) +2= 2k + 2$.  So $n =\frac {(2k)(2k+2)}8 = \frac {4k(k+1)}{8} = \frac {k(k+1)}2$.  Stop.   That's if you *didn't* have the insight that $8N+1$ is odd so $8N+1 = (2K+1)^2$, which makes the proof *much* shorter.  But even without it, the proof is straightforward.

Comment: I suppose a trick is to *NOT* get bogged down in proving that if $8|(m-1)(m+1)$ then $2$ divides one and $4$ divides the other.  That is true and it isn't difficult to prove but it's slightly tedious (it's one of those "*how* obscure and vague in my langauge vs. too many variables and considered cases should I be" proofs) and absolutely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

- If $n$ is a triangular number, then $n = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $8n+1 = 4k(k+1)+1 = (2k+1)^2$.
- If $8n+1$ is a perfect square, then $8n+1 = (2m+1)^2 \implies n = \frac{4m^2+4m+1-1}{8} = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ (because $8n+1$ is odd so it must be square of an odd number).

Comment: Even if it never occurs to one that the square must also be odd we would have $8n+1 = m^2$ we'd get $n = \frac {m^2 - 1}8 = \frac {(m-1)(m+1)}8$ so one of m-1 or m+1 is even.  If one is even the other is so if $m-1 = 2k$ then $m+1 = 2k + 2$ and .... it still follows.