# Please help me solve this number theory question.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

For what values of K is 
8k + 1 = a² 
Where a is an integer.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Triangular numbers: $1,3,6,10,15$ and so on

Comment: It is unclear how you want to use $p$-adic numbers. The sequence $s_n = n^2\bmod k$ is $k$-periodic, it is not hard to find $\{ n\in \Bbb{Z}, n^2 \equiv b \bmod k\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $8k+1 = a^2$, clearly $a$ has to be odd, i.e $a = 2j+1$.  Then $a^2 = 4j^2 + 4j + 1 = 4j(j+1) + 1$.  As one of $j, j+1$ must be even, we can rewrite this as $a^2 = 8 (j(j+1)/2) + 1$.  Hence $k = j(j+1)/2$; i.e $k$ must be a *triangular number* - 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ....

Comment: And conversely, if $k$ is a triangular number, then $8k+1$ is a perfect square, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281906/triangular-series-perfect-square-formula-8n1-derivation).

Answer (score 1):

$$8k + 1 = a^2, a,k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\iff a \text{ odd}$$
$$\iff a = 2m + 1, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\iff a^2 = 4m^2 + 4m + 1 = 4m(m+ 1) + 1 = 8k + 1$$
$$\iff 8k = 4m(m+1)$$
$$\iff k = \frac{1}{2}m(m+1)$$

And so $k$ has the form of triangular numbers including zero: $0,1,3,6,10 \dots$

This proof shows that the implication goes both ways. $8k + 1 = a^2$ implies $k$ triangular, and $k$ triangular implies that $8k + 1$ is a perfect square..